# POS Entry mode 5

Tags: credit-card, emv, pos

Who has the responsibility to pay for a purchase made with a VISA TC chip.
The purchase was made without PIN, POS entry 5 mode.
The acquirer, the bank, or the user?
Card was reported 12 hours after the purchase.

Tnks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about liability for card payment and not even closely related to programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because financial and legal issues instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or code you've written

Answer (score 0):

By TC, I assume you meant the transaction was offline approved with transaction certificate.
You cannot hold the merchant responsible as (1) the terminal and card are both emv compliant (2) verifying the signature in case of non CAT is not fool proof (3) no authentication if a CAT terminal.
The onus will be on card holder if the purchase is made outside the reporting time. If it is between the agreed time, bank will cover it. It is for these reasons offline limits are set to a low amount, do random transaction selection and send online, check consecutive offline counters..